# Using the cosmosdb SQLAPI, I'm able to create the partitionKey and ID I'm specifying, but no other content

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, json-serialization

I'm using the CosmosDB SQLAPI to create temporary storage of debug data during email processing.  I only have less than a dozen known senders, and only a couple of hundred known recipients of that email.  So, here's my code for Upserting into Cosmos.

```
messageEntity.PartitionKey = $"{messageEntity.SenderAddress}.to.{messageEntity.RecipientAddress}";
messageEntity.Id = $"{messageEntity.PartitionKey}.at.{messageEntity.Timestamp}";

var result = await container.UpsertItemAsync<MessageEntity>(messageEntity);
```

The `result` comes back `Created`, and I can see the **key** and **id** using the Cosmos Data Explorer.  But I do not see the rest of the messageEntity properties.

I've tried both with annotation...

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MessageEntity
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public MessageStatus Status { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and without - it doesn't make a difference.

I'm not seing any exceptions or errors.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the class definition for MessageStatus? That's what you're deserializing into. If the properties (including system properties, are not defined there too, they will not appear when you deserialize the response.

Comment: Mark, MessageStatus is an enum property of MessageEntity - along with several string, Guid, and other serializable properties.  And FYI - MessageEntity has a default constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to change the type on your Upsert call to dynamic instead of your POCO. Something like this.

```
var result = await container.UpsertItemAsync<dynamic>(messageEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the default format for **timestamp** includes illegal characters "/".  I'm surprised that I did not receive any errors.  The following format works just fine.  `Timestamp.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.ffff")`